# how to find a missing pair in pandas dataframe and fill with a dummy value

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have a dummy dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[2019-08-06,2019-08-08,2019-08-01,2019-10-12], 'Name':['A','A','B','C'], 'Type':['X','Y','Y','Z']})
```

There are 3 potential values for `Type`--- W,X,Y,Z
I want to find a missing pair for `Name` - `Type` and fill insert the row with Date Value '`0000-00-00'`

So in this example, all of A,B,C has no Type W / B and C has no X / C has no Y / A and B has no Z

Therefore, I will have to add 8 rows with Date `0000-00-00`

As a summary, what I need to do is ---

Find missing pairs of two columns and fill the other specific row with a dummy value.

EDIT --- Since I found an ValueError with the solutions below, I edited the dummy dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[2019-08-06,2019-08-07,2019-08-08,2019-08-01,2019-10-12], 'Name':['A','A','A','B','C'], 'Type':['X','X','Y','Y','Z']})
```

Comment: your data does not load. ` leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`

Comment: "There are 3 potential values for Type--- W,X,Y,Z", that's 4, not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) by levels from all combiantions from columns by [`MultiIndex.levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.levels.html) passed to [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Name','Type'])

df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels), fill_value='0000-00-00')
print (df)
                 Date
Name Type            
A    X     2019-08-06
     Y     2019-08-08
     Z     0000-00-00
B    X     0000-00-00
     Y     2019-08-01
     Z     0000-00-00
C    X     0000-00-00
     Y     0000-00-00
     Z     2019-10-12
```

EDIT: Error `ValueError:cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!` means there are duplicated pairs in `Name`, `Type`, solution for processing data is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2019-08-06','2019-08-08','2019-08-01','2019-10-12'], 
                   'Name':['A','A','B','C'], 
                   'Type':['X','X','Y','Z'], 
                   'col':list('abcd')})

print (df)
         Date Name Type col
0  2019-08-06    A    X   a
1  2019-08-08    A    X   b <-duplicated pair `A, X` - Name, Type
2  2019-08-01    B    Y   c
3  2019-10-12    C    Z   d
```

Solution is remove duplicates first by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), apply `reindex` for all combinations:

```
mask = df.duplicated(['Name','Type'])
df1 = df[~mask].set_index(['Name','Type'])

df1 = (df1.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels))
          .fillna({'Date':'0000-00-00', 'col':'missing'}).reset_index())
print (df1)
  Name Type        Date      col
0    A    X  2019-08-06        a
1    A    Y  0000-00-00  missing
2    A    Z  0000-00-00  missing
3    B    X  0000-00-00  missing
4    B    Y  2019-08-01        c
5    B    Z  0000-00-00  missing
6    C    X  0000-00-00  missing
7    C    Y  0000-00-00  missing
8    C    Z  2019-10-12        d
```

And last add all duplicated rows by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df[mask]]).sort_values(['Name','Type'], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  Name Type        Date      col
0    A    X  2019-08-06        a
1    A    X  2019-08-08        b
2    A    Y  0000-00-00  missing
3    A    Z  0000-00-00  missing
4    B    X  0000-00-00  missing
5    B    Y  2019-08-01        c
6    B    Z  0000-00-00  missing
7    C    X  0000-00-00  missing
8    C    Y  0000-00-00  missing
9    C    Z  2019-10-12        d
```

Comment: This assumes that Name and Type are categorical columns with the corresponding levels, otherwise you need to convert it. Also this is similar to mine ;-)

Comment: @jezrael Thank you, what if there is more columns and I only want to fill value in Date column?

Comment: @jezrael I got ValueError:cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: @YunTaeHwang - Error means there are for some combination `Name` and `Type` 2 or more datetimes, like if change first `Y` to `X`, then what should be expected output? Removed second `A, X` row, because duplicated?

Comment: @YunTaeHwang - I think if data are `df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2019-08-06','2019-08-08','2019-08-01','2019-10-12'], 
                   'Name':['A','A','B','C'], 
                   'Type':['X','X','Y','Z'], 
                   'col':list('abcd')})
`

Comment: @jezrael gotcha --- should I include datetime in that set_index as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223626/discussion-between-yun-tae-hwang-and-jezrael).